# Rabbitmq camel spring boot auto config

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, apache-camel, autowired, spring-rabbit

I have camel and rabbitmq configured like the following and it is working.  I am looking to improve the config setup.

**pom.xml**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-rabbitmq-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**application.yml**

```yaml
spring: 
  rabbitmq:
    host: rabbithost-url
    port: 5672
    username: my-user
    password: my-password
```

**config bean**

```java
@Configuration
public class CamelConfig {

    @Resource private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory(){
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHost(env.getProperty("spring.rabbitmq.host"));
        connectionFactory.setPort(Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty("spring.rabbitmq.port")));
        connectionFactory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);
        // more config options here etc
        return connectionFactory;
    }
}
```

**Route Example**

```java
@Component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

     from("direct:startQueuePoint")
          .id("idOfQueueHere")
          .to("rabbitmq://rabbithost-url:5672/TEST-QUEUE.exchange?queue=TEST-QUEUE.queue&autoDelete=false&connectionFactory=#rabbitConnectionFactory")
          .end();
    }
}
```

Would like to improve the following?  Or at least see if its possible?

**1)**  How do I leverage spring boot autowiring.  I feel like im duplicating beans by added the custom CamelConfig > rabbitConnectionFactory?  Its not using the RabbitAutoconfiguration?

**2)**  When I am using the connection factory I am referencing the rabbitmq-url and port twice?  I am adding it in the rabbitConnectionFactory bean object and in the camel url?  e.g.

```java
.to("rabbitmq://rabbithost-url:5672/ ..etc.. &connectionFactory=#rabbitConnectionFactory")
```

can I not just reference it once in the connection factory?  tried the following without the host as its included in connectionFactory but it did not work.

```java
.to("rabbitmq://TEST-QUEUE.exchange?queue=TEST-QUEUE.queue&autoDelete=false&connectionFactory=#rabbitConnectionFactory")
```

The 1st working example I am using is based off this.
 [camel.apache.org/rabbitmq example (see Custom connection factory )](http://camel.apache.org/rabbitmq.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found from looking at the newer docs on github.

Notice that now no url needed in the start of the route.

`.to(rabbitmq:exchangeName?options`

Full camel route example below

```
.to(rabbitmq:exchangeName?queueName&exchangeType=direct&connectionFactory=#rabbitConnectionFactory&autoDelete=false
```

Here is url:

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-rabbitmq/src/main/docs/rabbitmq-component.adoc